# Call two function at a single function call

Tags: java

I am not sure if it is as straight forward as I am writing but I have a use case in which two function call has to be done at the same time.

Example:

```
class ABC {
    int a;
    String b;

    setA(int x) {
        //..
    }

    setB(int y) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

So what I want is that when I call `setA()`, `setB()` should also implicitly be called,
ie I don't want to write:

```
setA(int x) {
    // ..
    setB(x);
}
```

Is there any way to do this? I thought of adding something like a listener so that when `setA()` is called my listener will call `setB()`. Is this an option?

Comment: Why don't you add a method `setAandB(...)`? And if those always have to be called together, why not remove the single setters then?

Comment: because setb(x) may also be called independenly... Usecase is like when setA(x) is called as a default value assign value to b based on x..

Comment: So, basically, `setB(int x)` and `setB(String strToX)`? Isn't that what you need? The latter would do some str to int conversion and then call `setB(someInt);`

Comment: If your question has been answered, or if it is no longer valid, please 'tick' to choose the most appropriate answer so everyone knows that the problem has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your goal of having setA() calls always followed by a setB() call without explicitly making the call seems quite silly.  Do you have an actual reason not to write:

```
public void setA(int x) {
   ...
  setB(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider all those smart and useful answers around.

If those are not helpful, you might be looking for some sort of [AOP solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) - the idea of that is exactly what you want: "If something calls firstMethod(), intercept that call, do any other stuff, then *maybe* call the wanted method, then do a bunch of another stuff." It's good for example for keeping the logging layer absolutely separated from the logic layer - the logic layer won't even know that it's being intercepted and logged.

BUT! Believe me, the problems with setting that up are usually **not** worth it and it's not exactly an OOP-compliant thing. But if your problem is **much** more complicated than the snippet you posted and you really could use this functionality, then [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) or [Spring AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html) are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

hmm...

```
setAandB(int x)
{
  seta(x);
  setb(x);
}
```

Does exactly what it says...

Answer (score 0):

You say in your comment that the user can call `setA(x);` which should also cause `setB(x);` to be called, so that if `setB(x);` isn't explicitly called by the user, it still has a value for both variables.

In this case, why don't you implement your getter method `getB();` such that is looks to see whether it has been set, and if not, it sets it accordingly...

```
public String getB(){
  if (b == null){
    // hasn't been set by the user, so lets set it to the value of 'a'
    setB(a);
    }
  return b;
  }
```

Now if the user only calls `setA(x);`, when they try to call `getB(x);` it will set the value of `b` before returning it.